Unit Tests passing in IDE and pipeline but failing with mvn clean install
I'm working in a project with Spring Boot and Java 11.
I have created the following UT, that when I launch it with the IDE (IntelliJ) it passes correctly and when I commit and push it to the pipeline in GitLab it passes as well. BUT when I launch a mvn clean install in my local it gives me the following error:
 @Test
    public void process_test() throws Exception {

        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("data/data.csv");
        StringBuffer reponse = reader.process(resource.getInputStream());

        File logs = File.createTempFile("tempFile-", ".txt");
        var out = new FileWriter(logs);
        out.write(reponse.toString());
        out.close();

        String resultatLog =  Files.readString(logs.toPath());

        assertTrue(resultatLog.contains("abcd"));

        logs.deleteOnExit();
    }

[INFO] 
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   ReaderTest.process_test:170 » MalformedInput


The line that gives that error is the following:
String resultatLog =  Files.readString(logs.toPath());

and I have tried to insert the charset also: (the charset is also defined in the POM)
String resultatLog =  Files.readString(logs.toPath(), Charsets.UTF_8);

In the gitlab-ci.yml I have the following:
build:maven:
  image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-11
  stage: build
  script:
    - "mvn clean install -B -U"
...

unit:test:
  image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-11
  stage: test
  script:
    - "mvn test -B -U"

I don't know why there are differences in the tests results between the pipeline/ide launch and the local mvn clean install.
Could anybody help me correct my mvn clean install?
Thank you very much!

First using ancient old Maven version... also based on the used JDK you are using an old Spring Boot version... furthermore why have you separated mvn clean install and mvn test ... you should lern the life cycle...install includes test... (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle)

@khmarbaise thank you for your comment! I just copied what it was done on the project I'm working on, I didn't wrote the yml. I will take in to account your comments if at any time I modify it.

Finally I've resolved the problem doing a refactor of the code:
@Test
    public void process_test() throws Exception {

        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("data/data.csv");
        StringBuffer reponse = reader.process(resource.getInputStream());

        File logs = File.createTempFile("tempFile-", ".txt");
        var out = new FileWriter(logs);
        out.write(reponse.toString());
        out.close();

        //Modified code
        byte[] b = {};
        try{
            b = Files.readAllBytes(logs.toPath());
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String resultatLog = new String(b);
        //End of the modified code

        assertTrue(resultatLog.contains("abcd"));

        logs.deleteOnExit();
    }

I still doesn't know why the mvn clean install it was failing, so if anybody knows I still want to know why it was wrong before.
